# Auto generate title for the image or big text in the content

Tags: java, auto-generate

I am working on the Content Based API, where user can create Questions, Blogs, Notes etc. We want to generate small title out of it which best describes them.

1. Is it possible to do it?
2. Are there libraries available do it in Java?

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: **1.** I'm sure it is. Anything is possible with Java :D **2.** Asking for third party libraries on SO is frowned upon and reason for closing of a question. **3.** This question is too broad, and is also reason for closing. **4.** Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you point to code or library before closing the question?

Comment: Java fans... too much coffee.